# ElevateZoom with slick slider

Tags: html, jquery

hi i am using slick slider and when i click "tm-prodetails-thumbs" navigation it changes but what i want to do is "tm-prodetails-thumbs a href". When changed, write a href attr values ​​"productDetailsZoom".

"tm-prodetails-image" instead of click
When there is a change, let the values ​​change.

I'm a little new to Jquery so I hope I don't get a minus from you.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12">
    <!-- Product Details Images -->
    <div class="tm-prodetails-images">
        <div class="tm-prodetails-largeimage">
            <img src="images/prdoduct-details-image-1.jpg"
                 data-zoom-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-1.jpg"
                 alt="product image">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="slick-prev"></button>
        <div id="image-gallery" class="tm-prodetails-thumbs">
            <a href="#"
               data-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-1.jpg"
               data-zoom-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-1.jpg">
                <img src="images/prdoduct-details-image-1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#"
               data-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-2.jpg"
               data-zoom-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-2.jpg">
                <img src="images/prdoduct-details-image-2.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#"
               data-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-3.jpg"
               data-zoom-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-3.jpg">
                <img src="images/prdoduct-details-image-3.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#"
               data-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-4.jpg"
               data-zoom-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-4.jpg">
                <img src="images/prdoduct-details-image-4.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#"
               data-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-5.jpg"
               data-zoom-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-5.jpg">
                <img src="images/prdoduct-details-image-5.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#"
               data-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-6.jpg"
               data-zoom-image="images/prdoduct-details-image-6.jpg">
                <img src="images/prdoduct-details-image-6.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="slick-next"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var blogs = {
        /* Product Details Zoom */
        productDetailsZoom: function () {
            $('.tm-prodetails-largeimage img').elevateZoom({
                gallery: 'image-gallery',
                // galleryActiveClass: 'active',
                zoomWindowWidth: 300,
                zoomWindowHeight: 100,
                scrollZoom: false,
                zoomType: 'inner',
                cursor: 'crosshair'
            });

        },
        /* Product Details Zoom Image Change */
        productDetailsImageZoomChange: function () {
            $('.tm-prodetails-thumbs').find('a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var largeImage = $(this).data('zoom-image');
                $('.tm-prodetails-largeimage').find('img').attr('data-zoom-image', largeImage);
                $('.tm-prodetails-zoomimage').attr('href', largeImage);
            });
        },
        /* Initializer */
        init: function () {
            blogs.productDetailsZoom();
            blogs.productDetailsImageZoomChange();
        }
    };
    blogs.init();

    $('#image-gallery').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        prevArrow: $('.slick-prev'),
        nextArrow: $('.slick-next'),

> Blockquote

autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true
    });
})(jQuery);
```